# Anonymous Function Error: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Google Developer Tools is displaying the following error when my PHP page uses the content from a javascript file (my_scripts.js):

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined scripts.js:1 (anonymous function)"

Content of my_scripts.js

```
$('a.button').click(function(){ 
    window.location.href = "another_page.php";         
});
```

The page and the script work as required. Clicking the element links to the requested page, but the error is there.

1) What causes the error?
2) Can it or should it be ignored?

Comment: It probably means that the code runs before jQuery is imported.

Comment: *"What causes the error?"* Your access to the undeclared variable `$`. *"Can it or should it be ignored?"* Errors should never be ignored. *"The page and the script work as required. "* Then you don't even needs this script, since it doesn't run either way.

Comment: `The page and the script work as required.` Are you sure? How do you debug it? I meant if `$` is undefined, the click handler cannot be fired

Comment: Please run a proper browser/debugger (like Chrome) that will report the exact line of your source where the error occurs.  Then, and only then, can you properly troubleshoot what is causing the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) It looks like your problem is that jQuery haven't been loaded.

Make sure you load jQuery before `scripts.js`.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

2) Errors should never be ignored.

Comment: No need for this to be a comment, it *answers* the question (almost certainly).

Comment: However, if really want to make a comment, don't write an answer. The intention of the 50rep comment limit is certainly not to post the comment as an answer instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Trying to understand how things work. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jquery libary BEFORE! Please download the jquery.min.js at http://www.jquery.com/download/
also, write like this:

```
$(doucment).ready(function(){

    $('a.button').on('click',function(){ 
        window.location.href = "another_page.php";         
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already included jQuery on your file, and still its not working you should try,

```
jQuery(doucment).ready(function(){
   jQuery('a.button').on('click',function(){ 
      window.location.href = "another_page.php";         
   });
});
```

This is causing as there might be some conflicting js files.